# How to do Integration testing for post actions that require anti-forgery token and authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, integration-testing, xunit

I am currently doing integration testing for my application which is a job portal system made with Asp.net core 6 MVC.

I can test Post actions like SignUp post Action method that require anti forgery token, or Get Action methods that require Authentication by creating the clients the following ways:

for anti forgery

```
            using var cookieHandler = new CookieContainerHandler();
            cookieHandler.Container.Add(
                _factory.Server.BaseAddress,
                new Cookie(antiforgeryTokens.CookieName, antiforgeryTokens.CookieValue));


            using var client = _factory.CreateDefaultClient(cookieHandler);
```

for Auth

```
            var provider = TestClaimsProvider.WithCompanyClaims();
            _client = _factory.CreateClientWithTestAuth(provider);
```

But I am facing issue with testing Post actions that require Authentication and anti forgery token like the following:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles =Roles.Company)]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostJob(JobPostingViewModel viewModel)
```

I would appreciate it if somebody showed me how to integration testing for post actions that require [Authorize(Roles =Roles.Company)] and [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

I have came up with this test but its not working

```
        [Fact]
        public async Task PostJob_ValidModel_ReturnsRedirectToAction()
        {
            // Arrange
            //var client = _factory.CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
            //{
            //    AllowAutoRedirect = false // Prevent automatic redirects in the test client
            //});

            //var responset = await _client.GetAsync("/CompanyArea/Jobs/PostJob");
            //var antiforgeryToken = responset.Headers
            //    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Key == "Set-Cookie").Value.FirstOrDefault();
            //antiforgeryToken=antiforgeryToken.Replace(".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.", "");

            //antiforgeryToken=antiforgeryToken.Replace("; path=/; secure; samesite=strict; httponly","");
            var antiforgeryTokens = await _factory.GetAntiforgeryTokensAsync();

            using var cookieHandler = new CookieContainerHandler();
            cookieHandler.Container.Add(
                _factory.Server.BaseAddress,
                new Cookie(antiforgeryTokens.CookieName, antiforgeryTokens.CookieValue));


            using var client = _factory.CreateDefaultClient(cookieHandler);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization= new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Test");

            var viewModel = new JobPostingViewModel
            {
                FieldId = 1,
                Description = "Test job posting",
                JobType = "Full-time",
                RequiredDegreeIds = new List<int> { 1, 2 },
                RequiredSkillIds = new List<int> { 3, 4 },
                Title = "Test job"
            };
            var formData = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "__RequestVerificationToken", antiforgeryTokens.CookieValue },
            { "FieldId", viewModel.FieldId.ToString() },
            { "Description", viewModel.Description },
            { "JobType", viewModel.JobType },
            { "RequiredDegreeIds", string.Join(",", viewModel.RequiredDegreeIds) },
            { "RequiredSkillIds", string.Join(",", viewModel.RequiredSkillIds) },
            { "Title", viewModel.Title }
        };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
            // Act
            var response = await client.PostAsync("/CompanyArea/Jobs/PostJob", content);

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.Redirect, response.StatusCode); // Check that the response is a redirect
            Assert.Equal("/CompanyArea/Jobs/PostedJobs", response.Headers.Location.OriginalString); // Check that the redirect location is correct
        }
```